# Professional curly braces in MTPro2 font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, brackets, braces, math-fonts

I've noticed the differences in typesetting between MTPro2 Lite and its complete version, so I even bought the license and installed the complete version onto my computer. Most of the features have been satisfactory except curly braces.

On my computer with complete MTPro2 font, curly braces look like this:
[image]

But when submitted to journals, which I assume also use MTPro2, they somehow make it look much better. They look like this:
[image]

For what it's worth, the following is how I configure `mtpro2`:

```
\usepackage[nofontinfo,zswash,straightbraces,subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}
```

***EDIT:***
And `pdffonts` on the journal PDF gives me:

```
~/Downloads > pdffonts jds1039.pdf  daeyounglim at Daeyoungs-MacBook-Pro.local
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
LBNECK+LMRomanCaps10-Regular         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    393  0
LBNECL+LMRoman9-Regular              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    394  0
LBNECM+LMRoman12-Bold                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    395  0
LBNECN+LMRoman8-Regular              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    396  0
LBNECO+MTSYN                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    397  0
LBNECP+LMRomanSlant10-Regular        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    422  0
LBNEDA+LMRoman10-Bold                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    420  0
LBNEDB+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    421  0
LBNEEC+LMRoman10-Italic              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    433  0
LBNEED+MTMI                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    208  0
LBNEEE+Times-Roman                   Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     202  0
LBNEEF+MTMIB                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    204  0
LBNEFF+LMMono10-Regular              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    212  0
LBNEOD+LMRomanDemi10-Regular         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    229  0
LBNEPD+MTEX                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    224  0
LBNEPE+LMSans10-Regular              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    219  0
LBNFAF+MSAM10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     234  0
LBNFAG+CMSY10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    242  0
LBNFBH+MSAM7                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     238  0
```

The normal text seems to be `lmodern` whereas the math font is no doubt `mtpro2` which gives Times Roman.

How do I make curly braces look like the journals'?

Comment: do you have the journal pdf? you can check which fonts it is using. the subscripts appear to be a lot bolder in your version as well?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do have the journal PDF but that doesn’t show up until it’s officially typeset and published by the journal, TeX file of which I don’t have…

Comment: I don't understand:, I mean, how did you generate the 2nd image above?  If you got it from a PDF then the pdffonts utility or viewer font menu should confirm what fonts it is using.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I screenshotted it from a PDF file I received from the journal. I didn't know pdffonts utility or viewer font menu would give me font info. I'll try that!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added the `pdffonts` output. The journal PDF is downloaded [here](https://jds-online.org/journal/JDS/article/1269/info) if that's useful. I thought this was more than just a font. I had assumed it had to do with configuring the `mtpro2` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text mode curly brackets are what I was looking for. Outside of math mode, `\{ \}` should normally work, but `mtpro2` makes LaTeX complain if you do this in text mode. The remedy is to use `\string{ \string}` instead, which also works inside math mode.